# Creating a Custom Identifier Property for Xamarin.Forms ImageButton (Similar to Tag or Name in WinForms)

Tags: c#, xamarin

In WinForms, I often use properties like Tag or Name to associate custom information with controls. I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms project, and I need a similar functionality for my ImageButton. While I attempted to use AutomationId, I found that it is read-only.

**In my XAML:**

```
<local:CustomImageButton CustomId="BIE Default startup image@0,0,0,0,640,640,100,0,0,640,640,640,640,0@@@0@1"
                         Source="a"
                         HeightRequest="60"
                         WidthRequest="60"
                         Aspect="AspectFit"
                         BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                         Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
```

I'm looking for a way to create a custom property, similar to Tag or Name in WinForms, for my ImageButton in Xamarin.Forms. However, my attempts with AutomationId have been unsuccessful due to it being read-only.

Request for Assistance:

Can someone guide me on creating a custom property for ImageButton that I can set and access in Xamarin.Forms? I need a property that is similar to Tag or Name in WinForms, allowing me to associate custom information with each ImageButton.

Comment: Use ClassId instead

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what i was looking for but now i got another exception: `User
System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'` at this line: `var menuItems = (System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>)menuListView1.ItemsSource;`

Comment: That’s a pretty basic C# error.  What is the type of ItemsSource?

Comment: @Jason I don't know. How can i find out?

Comment: It's your code.  It's whatever type you're assigning it.

Comment: or use the debugger to check the type at runtime

Comment: Can you show the code about set the ListView's ItemsSurce?